# Datagrid columns auto fill not working on auto generated columns

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I try to resize the columns of my DataGrid that the columns just take enough space they needed.

Can't upload an image of what I want it seems.

But for example:

```
Header      |Header         |
Content     |MoreContent    |
```

How can I make it:

```
Header |Header2    |
Content|MoreContent|
```

Tried this in the xaml file:

```
ColumnWidth="*"
```

And this:

```
MyDataGrid.AutoGeneratedColumns += MyDataGrid_AutoGeneratedColumns;

private void MyDataGrid_AutoGeneratedColumns(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var oColumn in OgonePaymentInfoDataGrid.Columns)
        {
            // This is how to set the width to *
            oColumn.Width = new DataGridLength(1.0, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
        }
    }
```

This is how I fill my DataGrid:

```
MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = items;
```

Comment: The columns should be auto-sized by default. Are you setting the width explicitly somewhere?

Comment: @mm8 yes this did the trick removing ColumnWidth="*"

Answer (score 1):

`ColumnWidth="*"` will stretch all DataGrid columns equally. you can use

```
<DataGrid ColumnWidth="{x:Static DataGridLength.SizeToCells}">

</DataGrid>
```

without additional event handlers for AutoGeneratedColumns event.

`ColumnWidth` property has type [DataGridLength](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridlength?view=netframework-4.8), and [SizeToCells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridlength.sizetocells?view=netframework-4.8) is one of possible values, which are defined as static properties.

Comment: Ok this seems to work but if the column content is smaller then the header the header will shrink . How to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

The columns are auto-sized by default. Make sure that you don't explicitly set the `Width` somewhere, i.e. remove `ColumnWidth="*"` and it should work just fine.